# How to Pass and get multiple parameters through in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am able to pass only one parameter in url and Since i am not able to pass multiple parameter,I have hard coded parameter as below.How to Pass and get multiple parameters through in rails?

```
#This value getting from url
address = params[:id]

#This value hard coded
parameter = "SSID"
```

I am able to get response from below request

```
http://localhost:3000/apitest/v1/get_request/10:11:55
```

But i need to pass request like as below

```
http://localhost:3000/apitest/v1/get_request/10:11:55,SSID
```

Below the code i am using.

```
module ApiTest
  module V1
    class GetRequestController < ApplicationController

      def show
        value = ''
        address = params[:id]
        parameter = "SSID"
        client = ClientApi.new
        response = client.get_call(address, parameter)
        redis_client = Redis.new
        access_token = redis_client["client:SATToken"]
        if access_token.nil?
          sat_client = SatClient.new
          response = sat_client.get_sat_token
          body = JSON.parse(response.body)
          if response.code == "200"
            access_token = body["access_token"]
            redis_client = Redis.new
            redis_client["client:SATToken"] = access_token
            return access_token
          else
            p "SAT endpoint returned #{response.code}"
            p "#{response.body}"
            raise "Retrieving SAT Token call failed"
          end
        end
        puts "response.status_code #{response.code}"
        if response.code == "200"
          value = JSON.parse(response.body)["parameters"][0]["value"]
          render json: value
        end

     end
    end
  end


end
```

Routes

```
namespace 'apitest' do
    namespace 'v1' do
      resources :get_request_controller
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass multiple parameters if you name them

```
http://localhost:3000/apitest/v1/get_request/10:11:55?parameter=SSID
```

This is saved in `params[:parameter]`. Then you can add more by adding them after an ampersand:

```
http://localhost:3000/apitest/v1/get_request/10:11:55?parameter=SSID&parameter2=something
```

where you can get `params[:parameter2]`

Comment: One More query i have.Is there way to call another method in resources.             resources :get_request_controller/set_opeartion.